# How to translate application to another language?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to translate application to another language?

I found this -> http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

SO what I need to do?

1) install gem

2) create fr (french) or it (italy) yml files in config/

3) ...

4)...

translate = use Locale.

.... Please help!

Comment: 5) I have no idea what you want. What is translating an application ?

Comment: hi. I have updated asnwer. I mean locale. use i18n  in RoR..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you output some text to the screen, use `I18n.t` (in views, can be `t`). So instead of (in view):

```
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
```

use:

```
<h1><%= t("message.hello") -%></h1>
```

Your locale files should be then:

```
# en.yml
message:
  hello:   "Hello, world!"

# de.yml
message:
  hello:   "Hallo, Welt!"
```

You can also translate texts you assign in controllers. Instead of `@message = "Hello, world"` use `@message = I18n.t("message.hello")`.

You can set locale with `I18n.locale = :en`. The tutorial [you already found](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) is a good start.

Note that there are also localised views. Instead of naming a view file like `index.html.erb` you can have `index.fi.html.erb` for Finnish, `index.pl.html.erb` for Polish, etc. The non-localised one will be rendered if the localised one cannot be found.